# Gulp, Compass and LiveReload - no style injection, page always reloads

Tags: compass-sass, gulp, livereload

Everything is *almost* working, compass is compiling the CSS and a few other tasks are running to minify, rename, rev etc. The problem is that when a style change occurs LiveReload is reloading the page instead of injecting the style. If I switch back to `compass watch` then style injection occurs. Is it possible to have style injection with Gulp, Compass and LiveReload? I hope so because if not I will have to run `compass watch` in 1 terminal and `gulp` in another which seems a bit clunky. Here is the relevant code from the `gulpfile.js`

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    uglify = require('gulp-uglify'),
    concat = require('gulp-concat'),
    compass = require('gulp-compass'),
    minifyCSS = require('gulp-minify-css'),
    rev = require('gulp-rev'),
    rename = require('gulp-rename'),
    clean = require('gulp-clean'),
    lr = require('tiny-lr'),
    server = lr(),
    livereload = require('gulp-livereload');

gulp.task('compass', function() {
  gulp.src('./static/scss/*.scss')
  .pipe(compass({
    css: 'static/css',
    sass: 'static/scss',
    image: 'static/images',
    font: 'static/fonts',
    javascript: 'static/js',
    comments: false,
    style: 'expanded',
    bundle_exec: true,
    require: ['wegowise_styles/compass']
  }))
  .on('error', function(err) {})
  .pipe(gulp.dest('./static/css/'))
  .pipe(livereload(server))
  .pipe(minifyCSS())
  .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'}))
  .pipe(rev())
  .pipe(gulp.dest('./static/production/'))
  .pipe(rev.manifest())
  .pipe(rename('css-manifest.json'))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('./static/production/'));
});

gulp.task('clean', function() {
  return gulp.src(['static/production'], {read: false})
  .pipe(clean());
});

gulp.task('watch', function() {
  gulp.watch('static/scss/**/*.scss', ['compass']);
  gulp.watch('static/js/**/*.js', ['scripts']);
});

gulp.task('default', ['clean', 'watch']);
```

ps. I am using the LiveReload chrome extension

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. I haven't seem in your code (maybe because you removed the rest of the file) when you start `tiny-lr`, i.e.:

```js
var gutil = require('gulp-util');

gulp.task('tiny', function(next) {
  server.listen(35729, function() {
    gutil.log('Server listening on port: ', gutil.colors.magenta(port));
    next();
  });
});

// add as a dependency in your watch task
gulp.task('watch', ['tiny'], function() {
  gulp.watch('static/scss/**/*.scss', ['compass']);
  gulp.watch('static/js/**/*.js', ['scripts']);
});
```

The error might be related to the `scripts` task as well, so maybe include it in the question so we can take a look. Maybe, finally, there is some other task causing the issue.

In order to be sure, I just created a test here, and created a `index.html` file inside the static folder, pointing to `css/file.css`.

Created a simple `static/scss/file.scss` with a `body` `background-color`. I've used the same code snippet you provided for the rest of the `gulpfile`.

Also created a `node-static` server and served all files under `static/` folder.

At the end, is there any other automated task involved in the building process?